# Batch Clipping using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, clip, batch, python-script-tool

I am trying to perform a batch clip using arcpy. I cannot seem to get the script to save where I want them to, with a specific name. I remove the "Ohio_" and rename them with "Summit_" what is in the directory ex. "Summit_CensusTracts".

Any input?

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "H:/Python_GIS/Summit_County_Project/Shapefiles"
# Variables
fcInput = "H:/Python_GIS/Summit_County_Project/Shapefiles/Ohio_Counties.shp"
fcOutput = "H:/Python_GIS/Summit_County_Project/Shapefiles/Summit_County_Updates/Summit.shp"

# Expression
whereClause = "COUNTY_NAM = 'SUMMIT'"

# Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(fcInput, fcOutput, whereClause)


# Processing

outFolder = "H:/Python_GIS/Summit_County_Project/Shapefiles/Summit_County_Updates"
clipFeature = "H:/Python_GIS/Summit_County_Project/Shapefiles/Summit_County_Updates/Summit.shp"
shpList = ["Ohio_CensusTracts.shp", "Ohio_Cities.shp", "Ohio_Hydro.shp", "Ohio_Roads.shp"]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(outFolder):
   for name in files:
      if name.startswith("Ohio_"):
         # shapefile name without extension
         shpName = os.path.splitext("Summit")[0]
         # absolute file path
         absFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,name))
         # output file path
         output_layer = outFolder
         # buffer
         arcpy.Clip_analysis(shpList, clipFeature, output_layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of errors in this script. Let's take a look at your clip function:

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis(shpList, clipFeature, output_layer)
```

You are adding a list of shapefile names in the first parameter. This should be a single feature layer or feature class. In the third parameter, you are adding an output folder path instead of explicitly defining the feature class to be created. See the [Clip](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm) help page for details on the function parameters.

Additionally, it appears as if you are running a select, yet fail to use the selected features `fcOutput` later in the script.